# Approximate ST_ShortestLine in geography (PostGIS)

Tags: postgis

Actually PostGIS has a function to get the shortest line:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ShortestLine.html

But as you can see, the support is only for geometry type, so we can't get the shortest line for a geography, that is a little weird if you think actually there is ST_Distance that works with geography.

Well, I would like to know a way to get the shortest line of two geometries of geography type (not just points).

For now, lets say I don't need a perfect method, but ideally can know what method can works in what circumstances.

Comment: spheroid_dist   |   sphere_dist geography [LINESTRING] examples using ST_Distance https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgis/2.3.9/ST_Distance.html

Comment: I agree that it feels odd that ST_Distance gives the shortest distance between the geographies but there does not seem to be a way to know between which two points the distance is. If the endpoints were known, then the curved line could be constructed as in https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/elevation-profiles-and-flightlines-with-postgis.

Comment: This is exactly why ST_ShortestLine once was written. I used the distance function in ArcView 3.x and couldn't get from what points the distance was measured. Then finding PostGIS made it possible to implement the functionality there. But everything is much more complicated when dealing with spheriod calculations.

Comment: have you tried `(st_shortestline(geog1::geometry, geog2::geometry))::geography`?

Comment: Yeah, it runs, will works for small distances, but for big ones will not D:

Comment: Do you mind adding an example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: The naive way is to dump points from one geometry and calculate the spherical distance using ST_DistanceSpheroid to each point of the second geometry. Then sort the results by distance and finally construct a line from those points.

Comment: Ufff, that is a way, and split geometries to segments or uniform points for polygons can helps to improve the precision, the cost sound high! xD. jbalk, geometry is planar, and the calculations does that, the idea of geography, is use spherical calculations, it will works for small distances, just because spherical calculations is similar to planar in small ons, and for do that, I would need transform the geometry to other CRS too, for a planar one.